# Eclipse Plugin Development: Adding a menu on right click on Tab of editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin

When we right click on a **tab** of an JavaEditor in eclipse, we get three options

```
1. Close  
2. Close Others  
3. Close All
```

I wanted to add an extra menu like this:

```
1. Close  
2. Close Others  
3. Close All  
4. Open File in Folder
```

After my own study I was able to locate the command/handler that does these operations in the *org.eclipse.ui* plugin. But I wasn't able to view the menu contributuion anywhere.

Specifically My questions are:

1. How can I add the 4th menu option in the popup menu?
2. In which plugin is the menuContribution that actually displays those 3 menus when I right click on a tab?

I have attached the screenshot of the closeOthers command in te plugin editor..Hope it makes my question clear.[image]

Comment: someone should know this.. please! someone?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug about this: [Bug 103045](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=103045). As you can see from the bug's history, it has not been solved, but there seems to be a workaround written there. Good luck.